# Exception 13 general protection fault....error code=0240

Tags: c++, exception, file-handling, general-protection-fault

```
exception 13: general protection fault at 08C7:210E error code 0240
              ax=0B0A, bx=0B0A,cx=0BZA,dx=0F97,di=0000,si=001E 
              ds=05CF limit=FFFF segment# 004D C:\TURBOC3\BIN\TC.EXE
              es=0F97 limit=1007 segment#
              cs=08C7 limit=470F segment# 0095 C:\TURBOC3\BIN\TC.EXE
              ss=05CF limit=FFFF segment# 004D C:\TURBOC3\BIN\TC.EXE
              error code=0240 limit=INVL segment#
```

I am getting this error while compiling on turboc++ and then it crashes.
I googled about it but could not get any help.
can you guys help me please?

regards and thanks in advance
tanmay darmorha